# When querying Parse pointer -- it is returning nil

Tags: ios, parsing, pointers

I have a table in Parse with columns

> ObjectId | Inviter(Pointer) | Active(Bool) | createdAt(date)

I am trying to populate a table with the Inviter information. So I'm trying to pull the pointer during the query.

Here is the method that pulls this data

```
- (void) getInvitationsForLoggedInUser {
    NSLog(@"entered getInvitationsForLoggedInUser");
    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Connection"];
    [postQuery whereKey:@"Active" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    [postQuery includeKey:@"Inviter"];

    [postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.tableData addObjectsFromArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"InvitationViewController - Loaded %lu connection objects from Parse for logged in user", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
            [self.invitationTableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"InvitationViewController - Could not find any connection objects from Parse");
        }
    }];
}
```

Here is where I am calling the data from the tableData array.

```
- (InvitationCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //TOFIX: In the view, I am seeing the entry but the fields are null. Need to check that the cell fields are getting populated.

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
    InvitationCell *cell = (InvitationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Create a new PFObject Object
    PFObject *connection = nil;

    connection = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    PFObject *inviterCodeName = [connection objectForKey:@"Inviter"];
    if (inviterCodeName == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not retrieve 'Inviter' object from connection object with id %@", [connection objectId]);
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM, h:mm a"];

    cell.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[connection updatedAt]];

    cell.codeName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inviter Code Name: %@", inviterCodeName[@"codeName"]];
    if (inviterCodeName[@"description"] == nil) {
        cell.codeNameDescription.text = @"";
    } else {
        cell.codeNameDescription.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", inviterCodeName[@"description"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Just for completeness,
these are all called in this lifecycle method

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self getInvitationsForLoggedInUser];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.invitationTableView reloadData];
}
```

Now, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I am successfully retrieving the Connection object. When I try to get the "inviterCodeName" object, it is ALWAYS nil.

I only have one row in the table that meets these requirements while I'm testing this, and it IS successfully populated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is meant by "I only have one row in the table that meets these requirements while I'm testing this, and it IS successfully populated."? Also, `[self.invitationTableView reloadData];` in the `viewWillAppear` method is likely invoked before the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is completed (i.e., no data yet, so don't update the table yet).

Comment: I have a row in the table that is getting queried to meet the criteria. Let me try moving the reloadData out of viewWillAppear

Comment: Same issue unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be an asynchronous issues. The table was loading before the background parse thread was returning data. I switched the call to be synchronous.

I'm not 100% sure this is the 'correct' way to do it, but it did solve the issue.